# Camera won't close after image is taken using intent

Tags: android, camera

I want to create a simple app that opens the camera, takes a picture and after the user accepts this picture, close the camera and show it in an image view.
Note that for now I don't want to save this image, only show it.
I used the code from the android docs to do this but the camera is not closed after picture is taken and therefore I can't see the picture in the image view.
The code is taken from the android docs so it is really frustrating it doesn't work.

Anyonw knows why?

Thanks in advance!

My Java code is this:

```
 @Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    //here is the camera request
    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
}


static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

My layout is this (most of it was prepared by the full screen activity so the only thing important is the ImageView):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context="com.gj_games.cameratest.CameraInfo">

<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc. -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
            style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dummy_button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I also specified the uses-feature in the manifest like this:

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The code is taken from the android docs so it is really frustrating it doesn't work.

You seem to think that the problem is with the documentation. It is not. It is with your chosen camera app.

`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` will start up some camera app. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of different camera apps pre-installed on the ~10,000 Android device models. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of additional camera apps that the user can install from the Play Store or elsewhere. Your code will wind up starting any one of these.

And some of those camera apps have bugs.

There is very little that you can do about this directly. Either live with the fact that some camera apps have bugs, or do not use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: What other way do you suggest?

Comment: @GiliJacobi: Use the camera APIs directly (`android.hardware.Camera`, `android.hardware.camera2.*`) or via a wrapper library (Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Use this Code to achieve this with android Runtime permission:

Runtime Permissin we need API 23 or greater than 23.  [Know more..](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

This is **MainActivity.Java** code : Here i used Runtime Permission , if you will run your app API 23 or grater this will show a `dialog` and ask about permission.And i used Here `startActivityForResult` which will return image after capturing.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button ;
    ImageView imageView ;
    Intent intent ;
    public  static final int RequestPermissionCode  = 1 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        EnableRuntimePermission();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                startActivityForResult(intent, 7);

            }
        });
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 7 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    public void EnableRuntimePermission(){

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
        {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"CAMERA permission allows us to Access CAMERA app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestPermissionCode);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int RC, String per[], int[] PResult) {

        switch (RC) {

            case RequestPermissionCode:

                if (PResult.length > 0 && PResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission Granted, Now your application can access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission Canceled, Now your application cannot access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

**main_activity.xml** Code : Here i used ImageView and Button, after clicking on button it will capture image show to the imageview.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.android_examples.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFF9C4">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <Button
        android:text="Click here to capture image using camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**Menifest Code :** Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` for permission of Camera.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android_examples.captureimagecamera_android_examplescom">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, how this affects the fact that the camera app is not returning control to the app that is starting the camera app.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Yes i'm going to edit & i will explain all the thing.